# How do I correlate data from customEvents dataset to the requests dataset in Application Insight logs?

Tags: azure-application-insights

We built a React webapp that makes fetch calls to WebAPI2 services hosted on the same website.  I've added Application Insights to the application and the server code.  There are some external web requests that run in the WebAPI services and I wanted to track the timings of those calls and compare them to the overall request duration.

I can see Fetches getting populated in the requests data.  I also see customEvents being recorded.  The problem is that I can't seem to correlate these two datasets.  None of the calls in the requests have an operation_Id that match the operation_Id or operation_ParentId in the customEvents.  I had thought that the whole purpose of these properties was to associate the calls with each other.

I saw this article that talks about some new W3C distributed tracing that can be used for correlation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/correlation).  I think that's for a different issue of dealing with server farms but even so, I've tried enabling those parameters without any luck either.

I also enabled the enableCorsCorrelation on the javascript config without that affecting anything I could tell.  But I think that setting is only useful to correlate across different AI resources.

I am using a current version of AI's SDK.  I notice that the source of these entries are coming from the different parts of the SDK.  Our customEvents are written by dotnet:2.8.1-22898.  The Fetch requests are written by web:2.8.1-19196.

Could the issue be sampling?  I've tried to open the firehouse... I have 100% Data Sampling on the Dashboard.  I have left the defaults for javascript config and applicationInsights.config on the server.

Has anyone had success correlating data in a customEvents dataset with other datasets?

Comment: yes, that is what the operation_id fields are for: correlation. so ideally there would be operations that are the same, events "inside" that request would have the same operation id and you'd be able to use the end to end details feature on a request in search and see what events are inside that request.  how are you doing the custom events code?  are you creating new telemetry client/etc?  are you doing async stuff?  are you manually setting operation id somehow/somewhere

Comment: The webapi controllers are setup as async functions.  Because the calls happening inside the controller are to other webservices asynchronously also.  I am creating a new stopwatch and new TelemeteryClient before.  After the webservice call, I stop the stopwatch and call .TrackEvent() to the TelemetryClient.

Comment: if you're doing that, you'd have to grab the operation id at the beginning of your request before async, and manually pass that along / set that on telemetry events you create

Comment: I'm not sure where to grab the operationId from. The request coming from the fetch on the server doesn't have a request header called operationId. I see in the cookies an ai_user=4Llc3|2019-03-28T21:35:43.354Z; and an ai_session=kj97v|1553808944064|1553809178668.205;. Are those extra params in the ai_session something that gets interpreted into an operationId?